# Woocommerce: programmatically add links if products has a tribute value

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to add a link to a product if it has a certain attribute value. 
This is what I have

```
function stilart_link() {
        echo '<p class="stilart">Mere i samme stil: </p>';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_stilart');
     foreach($terms as $term){  
     if($term->name == 'Rock'){
        echo '<p class="stilart"><a href="/stilart/rock"> <u>Rock-noder</u></a></p>';
     }
else if($term->name == 'Musical'){
        echo '<p class="stilart"><a href="/stilart/musical"> <u>Musical-noder</u></a></p>';
     }
else if($term->name == 'Disney'){
        echo '<p class="stilart"><a href="/stilart/disney"> <u>Disney-noder</u></a></p>';
     }      
else if($term->name == 'Filmmusik'){
        echo '<p class="stilart"><a href="/stilart/filmmusik"> <u>Filmmusik</u></a></p>';
     }  
else if($term->name == 'Jul'){
        echo '<p class="stilart"><a href="/stilart/jul"> <u>Julenoder</u></a></p>';
     }  
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'stilart_link' );
```

It does work. But I wonder if it could be done automatically to avoid long code.
This is what I am looking for:
a product has a value that belongs to the tribute "stilart". Eg. "Disney". On that product I want to add a link to /stilart/disney. And the same procedure with other values of the tribute "stilart – eg. Muscal, filmmusik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slug and title property that came from $term object. 
Try like this:

```
    function stilart_link() {
        echo '<p class="stilart">Mere i samme stil: </p>';
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_stilart');
         foreach($terms as $term){  
             echo '<p class="stilart"><a href="/stilart/'.$term->slug.'"> <u>'.$term->name.'</u></a></p>'; 
        }
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'stilart_link' );
```

Comment: just needs a <a href="/stilart/